# 'Device' object has no attribute 'wavefront_size_nv'

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I am using the python library cldemosaic (https://github.com/nevion/cldemosaic) to leverage the Opencl-based debayer. When I was trying to import the library:

```
import pyopencl
from kernel_common import *
```

The error occurred:

> AttributeError: 'Device' object has no attribute 'wavefront_size_nv'

Has anyone used this library and got any idea how to solve this?

Thanks,

Comment: That's an NVIDIA-only attribute. They shouldn't be checking it on non-NVIDIA hardware. What is your GPU?

Comment: I am using NVIDIA Tesla K80.

Comment: Good point! I just saw the "nv" on the end. In any case, this appears to be an cldemosaic issue, so best to take it up with them on their github.